# Raise error if the input is False (Boolean) while uploading excel sheet via import_export in Django Form

Tags: django, excel, django-models, django-forms, django-import-export

I have a Django form through which I am uploading an excel sheet to Database,

Here, some columns have boolean fields (True/False).

In such fields (e.g. block_covered, village_covered etc) , I want to raise an error such as: **"This field can not be false"**, whenever the field value is False(0), so that it only takes the value which are True(1) and ignore the user/myself to give false boolean value as input in excel sheet while uploading i.e. prevent them from uploading the sheet.

The related files are as below.

Model.py

```py
BOOL_CHOICES = ((True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No'))
UNIT_CATEGORIES = (('ABC', 'ABC'), ('XYZ', 'XYZ'))
  
class GroupDetail(models.Model):
    unit_type = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=UNIT_CATEGORIES)
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    unit_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    districts_covered = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Districts Covered "yes/no"'), choices=BOOL_CHOICES)
    block_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    block_covered = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Block Covered "yes/no"'), choices=BOOL_CHOICES)
    village_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    village_covered = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Village Covered "yes/no"'), choices=BOOL_CHOICES)
    number_of_group = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    number_of_farmers = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(1000)])
```

Form.py

```py
class add_to_database(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:

        model = GroupDetail

        fields = ["unit_type", 
                  "state_name",                   
                  "unit_name", 
                  "district_name", 
                  "districts_covered ", 
                  "block_name", 
                  "block_covered", 
                  "village_name", 
                  "village_covered", 
                  "number_of_group", 
                  "number_of_farmers"]

        labels = {
            "unit_type":"Unit Type", 
            "state_name":"State Name",             
            "unit_name":"Unit Name", 
            "district_name":"District Name", 
            "districts_covered":"Districts Covered (Yes/No)", 
            "block_name":"Block Name", 
            "block_covered":"Block Covered (Yes/No)", 
            "village_name":"Village Name", 
            "village_covered":"Village Covered (Yes/No)", 
            "number_of_group":"Number of groups", 
            "number_of_farmers":"Number of farmers"}

        widgets = {
            "unit_type":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "id":"unit_type_id"}),
            "state_name":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "id":"state_name_id"}),            
            "unit_name":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "id":"unit_name_id"}),
            "district_name":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "id":"district_name_id"}),
            "districts_covered":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "id":"districts_covered_id"}),
            "block_name":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "id":"block_name_id"}),
            "block_covered":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "id":"block_covered_id"}),
            "village_name":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "id":"village_name_id"}),
            "village_covered":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "id":"village_covered_id"}),
            "number_of_group":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "id":"number_of_group"}),
            "number_of_farmers":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "id":"number_of_farmers_id"})
        }

    def clean_number_of_groups(self, *args, **kwargs):
        number_of_groups= self.cleaned_data.get('number_of_groups')
        if number_of_groups== 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("number_of_groups can Not be 0.")
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Views.py

```py
def update_info(request):

    fetch_data_from_database = GroupDetail.objects.all()
    form_details = add_to_database(request.POST or None)
    if form_DAMU_details.is_valid():
        print(form_DAMU_details)

        xyz_resource = GroupDetailResource()
        dataset = Dataset()
        new_resource_info = request.FILES['myfile']


        if not new_resource_info .name.endswith('xlsx'):
            # messages.info(request, "Wrong data format, Kindly rectify. ")
            messages.error(request, "Wrong data format or Data Does not meet the Reuirements, Please check all the fields Again")
            return render(request, 'update_info_and_Readme_files.html')

        
        imported_data = dataset.load(new_resource_info.read(), format='xlsx')
        for data in imported_data:
            value = GroupDetail(
                data[0],
                data[1],
                data[2],
                data[3],
                data[4],
                data[5],
                data[6],
                data[7],
                data[8],
                data[9],
                data[10],
                data[11]
            )
            value.save()
        messages.success(request, "Data Inserted Successfully")
    else:
        print("Form is invalid")
        print(form_details.errors)
    return render(request, 'update_info_and_Readme_files.html', {"form_details": form_details, "fetch_from_DAMU_database": fetch_data_from_database})
```

admin.py

```
@admin.register(GroupDetail)
class GroupDetailAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("unit_type", 
                  "state_name",                   
                  "unit_name", 
                  "district_name", 
                  "districts_covered ", 
                  "block_name", 
                  "block_covered", 
                  "village_name", 
                  "village_covered", 
                  "number_of_group", 
                  "number_of_farmers")
```

resource.py

```
class GroupDetailResource(resources.ModelResource):
    """Group Resources Details """
    class Meta:
        model = GroupDetail

    def before_import(self, imported_data, using_transactions, dry_run, **kwargs):
        for data in imported_data:
            if int(data[10]) == 0:
                raise ValidationError('Village covered Can Not be 0.'
                                      'Error in row with id = %s' % data[10])
```

After adding validation in views.py,

now the terminal is showing this

```
Form is invalid

<ul class="errorlist"><li>unit_type<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>state_name<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li>......... and so on..........
```

The form is actually an external excel file uploader with import_export module of Django, and validation is required on the fields/columns of the excel sheet.

[image]

How to do so?

Comment: You probably don't want to use `forms.TextInput()`s for those boolean fields, by the way...

Comment: @AKX what should it be replaced with?

Comment: `forms.CheckboxInput` sounds about correct, don't you think? As an aside, you might want to look at `crispy-forms` to make it easier to render your forms using Bootstrap styles.

Comment: Your view is also incorrect in that it doesn't really use or validate the form at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

### Override each of the boolean fields in the form

... with a boolean field that has `required=True`:

```
class add_to_database(forms.ModelForm):
    village_covered = forms.BooleanField(..., required=True)
    # (repeat for other boolean fields that are required)

    class Meta:
        ...
```

### Or add validation functions:

```
class add_to_database(forms.ModelForm):
    ...

    def clean_village_covered(self, value):
        if not value:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Village covered must be set")
        return value
```

Comment: Hiii @AKX, I am new to Django, Can you please elaborate, on how to add a validation function for boolean value for any of the one fields in the Model.py.

Comment: for any of village_covered, block_covered or districts_covered

Comment: If they're always true, they don't need to be in the model at all. There's no point separately storing data that is always `True`. But to answer your question, [see Django's documentation on validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/validators/#writing-validators).

Comment: I have added the line ```village_covered = forms.BooleanField(label='Village Covered "yes/no"', required=True)``` in the Forms.py, but it is not overriding. uploading with the sheet with columns named ```village_covered``` having false values.

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment, you aren't using the form data, or even calling `form.is_valid()`. Please read up on how Django's forms work.

Comment: I have updated ```views.py```, ```admin.py```, ```resource.py```, still not working. Can you have a look at updated question?